# Inconsistent reminder for bounty grace period and expirations

Tags: feature-request, bounty, email, grace-period

I recently started a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113749/how-to-create-a-solr-core-using-docker-solrs-image-extension-mechanism) by me. Due to personal circumstances I wasn't able to grant the bounty last week.

I received a reminder via mail that the bounty will be auto closed after the 24h grace period. I received the email at 11th of september 02:02 CEST. I was surprised to find that the bounty was already closed when I visited Stack Overflow on the same day at about 19:30.

Could we please include the date and time of the auto closing of the bounty in the email (preferably in the title) so that it's clear when exactly this will happen? And could the Stack Overflow team please reassure that those reminders are sent on time? I might have received the bounty reminder late because of my mail client settings. But I'm not totally sure on that.

Comment: The system only knows about UTC days FYI.

Comment: @TinyGiant The problem is that the mailing system and the bounty system aren't aligned. I received an email about the grace period being opened hours after it was opened in reality.

Answer (score 4):

If the system can't email users when the grace period starts, the grace period could be increased to two days, so that users have one and a bit days from when they get the email to accept a bounty.

My most recent [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4856644/revisions) was auto-accepted 7 hours ago, and I got my grace email 10 hours ago (11:01 am AEDT), meaning that I only had three hours to choose the best answer for my bounty.